# Can I "profile" using Instruments for memory leaks using a Test Case? (i.e. focused run on a defined area of code)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

Can I "profile" for memory leaks using a Test Case?  (i.e. focused run on a defined area of code)  I tried changing my profile for my iPhone app to Unit Tests and then noted the "profile" option disappeared.

My goal (requirement) I guess is to be able to isolate a specific method, and then run the Instruments memory leak profiling across this specific method and observe results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to launch your application in Instrument, wait a little and tap a button that will run the specific method you're looking for.

You can then select the timespan where the method ran by dragging the time bar  with the option key.

Comment: thanks gcamp - in my case I have a whole lot of activity after I "press the button in question" so to speak - I wanted to be able to segregate off a specific underlying method...

Comment: That's just impossible with the current version of Instrument. You could always make a new command line utility target that only call your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a breakpoint in your tests, use Instruments to attach to the process, and then resume. Don't forget to hit Record like I did :)